# SQL - What is wrong on this procedure execute

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_employee
(emp_license IN trkdriver.L#%TYPE) 
IS
result VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
select e# INTO result
from trkdriver where l#='emp_license';
END;
/
```

Above is my procedure

```
SQL> desc trkdriver;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 E#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 L#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
```

I tried to

```
SQL> execute verify_employee('10001');
BEGIN verify_employee('10001'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "USER1.VERIFY_EMPLOYEE", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

What did i do wrong, i just want to try a simple procedure which will select base on the employee license id that i input

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `''` as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_employee
(emp_license IN trkdriver.L#%TYPE) 
IS
result VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
select e# INTO result
from trkdriver where l#=emp_license;
END;
/
```

end run it:

```
execute verify_employee(10001);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but how do i display out result after the select statement.

Comment: Try to add `dbms_output.put_line( result);`. Before `execute` you need to run `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` command.

Answer (score 0):

`l#` is number, and you are comparing it with string :
`... where l#='emp_license';`